# Printing a NULL Terminated String (PCL 5)

Tags: c#, winforms, null

I have a PCL 5 (Print Command Language) file that I am reading into a textbox and then sending the contents of the textbox to a PCL 5 printer. This has been working great so far, but if the PCL 5 file contains raster data it will always contain a NULL value. When I read a string that contains a NULL character into a textbox, the string is terminated. Thus I end up sending an incomplete PCL file to the printer and it prints garbage print.

```
    public static class BinaryFile
    {
        private static string[] __byteLookup = new string[256];

        static BinaryFile()
        {
            //CHARACTERS: All Control ASCII Characters
            for (int i = 0x00; i < 0x20; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = ((char)i).ToString(); }

            // Display printable ASCII characters
            for (int i = 0x21; i < 0x7F; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = ((char)i).ToString(); }

            __byteLookup[0] = "\x00";
        }
```

I have tried changing the `_byteLookup[0]` to a literal by making it read `@"\x00"` or `@"\0"` but this causes the data not to be read by the printer. The printer literally prints out the \0 or \x00. I need to somehow maintain the NULL value without the string being terminated so the printer can properly interpret the data. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use a textbox? Can you not pass the raw data directly to the printer instead?

Comment: Sometimes I need to make a small modification to the file and the print it out to see if the change I made corrected an issue.

Comment: You need to figure out what character you want to print in place of the null. To be honest I'd probably look at an alternative solution (e.g. write to a file and open it in Notepad++, then detect when Notepad++ closes / saves the file before continuing)